# How to prevent WP-CLI shell from exiting when an exception occurs?

Tags: wp-cli

I am using WP-CLI shell to quickly debug some code, but every time I run into a `fatal` exception (e.g. undefined constants/functions) the shell exits and I lose my shell session. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
wp> new DoesntExist();
Fatal error: Class 'DoesntExist' not found in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/REPL.php(37) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Shell exits..

Comment: Have you tried: $ wp shell --basic

Comment: Yes, I have. Doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: @prosti have you used Boris before with WP-CLI? Apparently that would work but I cannot find documentation aside from it being mentioned here - http://wp-cli.org/commands/shell/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809841/is-it-possible-to-redirect-boris-output-php-interactive-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behavior of WP-CLI's built-in PHP REPL. If you look at the [wp shell documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/shell/), it shows that you can also use the Boris or PsySH PHP REPLs.

The [Boris REPL](https://github.com/borisrepl/boris) does not seem to be actively maintained; however the [PsySH REPL](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh) has fairly recent maintenance, and it fixes the problem that you're experiencing.

The easiest way to integrate **PsySH** with **WP-CLI** is to use the [wp-cli-psysh](https://github.com/schlessera/wp-cli-psysh) plugin:

```
# Make sure WP-CLI is up to date
wp cli update

# Install the plugin
wp package install git@github.com:schlessera/wp-cli-psysh.git
```

After installing the plugin, running **wp shell** should show you a PsySH header that's similar to this:

```
$ wp shell

Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.1-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman

>>>
```

Comment: I'm noticing installing `schlessera/wp-cli-psysh` requires `memory_limit` > 512M, or install process will run out of memory. Setting 1024M worked everywhere, I didn't bother trying intermediary values.